# Get new mean from glmrob

Tags: r, glm

I need to report the mean, and SD of two groups for a specific variable, as well as the odds ratio of the two groups using robust logistic regression. The variable does have outliers. I instead want to report the robust mean and sd with a method that is similarly used in the robust logistic regression.

I simply want to get the new robust calculated mean and SD of the first term using the same methods from `robustbase::glmrob` R function. Method is default (method="Mqle") and family=binomial(link = "logit"). I calculated the Huber M-estimator of the mean and SD using `MASS::hubers(x, k=1.3450)` but I am not sure this is the estimator method used in `robustbase::glmrob`. Do you know what method is used and how I can use that method to calculate the robust mean and SD in R? Based on reading the original papers, it seems that to get a robust estimator of variance, they choose a simple M-estimator (Huber’s proposal 2). This variance estimator is calculated using `MASS::hubers()`, not `MASS::huber()`. The latter is based on the median absolute deviation (MAD) scale. However, glmrob does seem to use a robust mean in the formulas. I still believe its better to report robust means and SD so that the summary stats and model and comparable.

method="Mqle" fits a generalized linear model using Mallows (Mallows quasi-likelihood estimator) or Huber type robust estimators, as described in Cantoni and Ronchetti (2001) and Cantoni and Ronchetti (2006).

Eva Cantoni and Elvezio Ronchetti (2001) Robust Inference for Generalized Linear Models. JASA 96 (455), 1022–1030.

Eva Cantoni and Elvezio Ronchetti (2006) A robust approach for skewed and heavy-tailed outcomes in the analysis of health care expenditures. Journal of Health Economics 25, 198–213.

Here is an example:

Here is an example dataframe with a binomial response variable "Group", a numeric variable and covariable.

```
> df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(2,10))),
           variable = c(2,6,1,2,2,2,4,0,2,6,7,19,5,6,0,10,5,2,5,0),
           covariable = c(19,22,16,18,18,19,19,15,18,13,16,16,19,17, 21,12,14,19,18,18)
)

> df

   group variable covariable
1      1        2         19
2      1        6         22
3      1        1         16
4      1        2         18
5      1        2         18
6      1        2         19
7      1        4         19
8      1        0         15
9      1        2         18
10     1        6         13
11     2        7         16
12     2       19         16
13     2        5         19
14     2        6         17
15     2        0         21
16     2       10         12
17     2        5         14
18     2        2         19
19     2        5         18
20     2        0         18
```

Calculate the standard mean and SD

```
> aggregate(variable ~ group, df, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
  
group   variable.mean variable.sd
1     1           2.7         2.0
2     2           5.9         5.6
```

Using robust logistic regression. Notice that rows 15 and 20 are outliers and are thus weighted. These outliers are due to the variable, not covariable. I know this because the weights hardly changed when I removed the covariable term.

```
> robustbase::glmrob(group ~ variable + covariable  , data=df, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>% summary()

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.264760   4.218720  -0.300    0.764
variable     0.280474   0.208623   1.344    0.179
covariable   0.006005   0.220648   0.027    0.978
Robustness weights w.r * w.x: 
 18 weights are ~= 1. The remaining 2 ones are
    15     20 
0.7611 0.7543 

Number of observations: 20 
Fitted by method ‘Mqle’  (in 7 iterations)

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

No deviance values available 
Algorithmic parameters: 
   acc    tcc 
0.0001 1.3450 
maxit 
   50 
test.acc 
  "coef"
```

Calculate the Huber M-estimator of the mean and "SD". Notice that the mean and SDs are different from the original. I "think" that the same M-estimator method used in MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450) to estimate the mean and variance is used in `glmrob(method="Mqle")` function. If not, please correct me.

```
> aggregate(variable ~ group, df, function(y) c(mean.h = MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450)$mu, sd.h = MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450)$s))
  group variable.mean.h  variable.sd.h
      1             2.6            2.2
      2             5.1            4.4
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the mean of the predicted values (you could use `predict()`)?  The mean for some alternative set of covariates (you could use `predict()` with the `newdata` argument)? Are you fitting an intercept-only model? Could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: @BenBolker I've updated the question with an example and further explanation.

Comment: Looking more closely at your analysis, I'm still not sure what you're doing. You're fitting a robust GLM with `group` as a binomial response. To me that seems completely different from fitting robust means within each group (which is what you're trying to compare to). Are you sure you don't want to do something like `lmrob(variable ~ group + covariable)` ... ???)

Comment: I am comparing a nutrient intake "variable" between individuals with and without the disease (group). Since my question is to see if nutrition is a predictor of disease, my model should be correct. I do want odds ratio estimates to see the likelihood of having a disease with a 1 unit increase in wholegrains. @BenBolker

Comment: I'm not sure your approach makes sense. It might - I'm not sure it **doesn't** make sense - but I would consider getting clarification about the underlying approach on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), then possibly coming back here for advice on the computational details. AFAIK, `glmrob` works by computing a robust estimate of the *deviance*, not by computing robust estimates of the means in each group ...

Comment: I've confirmed my model with a statistician. You may be right; glmrob estimates the parameter β and variance via M-estimation. This method rescales the residuals.

Comment: To be clear, I think your `glmrob` model is fine, and your comparison of robust means by group is fine. I'm just not sure there's a straightforward way to compare those two results.

Comment: I will ask this question on CrossValidated